# Use docker-compose on host from container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to execute docker-compose on the host network from inside a container.
Following [this](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) post I mounted my docker socket already and I'm able to create containers on my host machine.
But instead of plain docker I want to use docker-compose.

How can I achieve my goal, do I have to mount something like a docker-compose socket?

Comment: Just install docker-compose in container. It should work like expected.

Comment: Oh yea, it actually works as expected... definitely not my proudest question. Thank you.